# Fish alias pass multiple arguments, access specific argument

Tags: fish

I would like to create an alias in script for creating `pull-requests` using `hub`.

I'm planning on creating a function like this.

```
# PR 
function pr --description 'hub pr'
    hub pull-request -b $argv[0] -m $argv[1];
end
```

The `-m` part can be optional though.

So I can all it like this `pr 'branch here' 'message here'`

But I get an error saying `Array index out of bounds`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
function pr -d 'git pull-request' -a branch message
    set -q message[1]
    and set message -m $message
    hub pull-request -b $branch $message
end
```

Comment: Note the `message[1]` here. The way `-a` currently works is that the variable is always defined, so you need to check if it contains anything.

Answer (score 2):

Fish arrays start at index 1, so your `$argv[0]` is wrong here. Use `$argv[1]` instead of that, and `$argv[2]` instead of the `$argv[1]` you currently have.

However, currently any element except 1 will result in an array-index-out-of-bounds error if you try to access it and it isn't set, so you need to check if it is with `set -q argv[2]`.

```
# PR 
function pr --description 'hub pr'
    set -l message
    if set -q argv[2]
        set message -m $argv[2]
    end
    hub pull-request -b $argv[1] $message;
end
```

(Also, https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/826 discusses removing index-out-of-bounds errors)

Answer (score 1):

Got it. But `-m` is not optional in this case.

```
# PR
function pr --description 'git pr' --argument-names message branch
        hub pull-request -m $message -b $branch;
end
```

And then you can type `pr 'message' 'branch'`

Comment: How `-m` is optional now ?

Comment: I guess it's not. This is what I came up with and I didn't accept this as an answer. And as I remember `-m` can be optional, doesn't have to be.

Comment: Amusingly, this is exactly the function I was trying to write when I looked up how to give args to aliases.

Answer (score 1):

There is another way to check your input using the `test` method in combination with `count`. Here is an example checking for greater than (`gt`) 1.

```
if test (count $argv) -gt 1;
    set r_args $argv[2..-1];
```